# SQL Server and SSIS Permission issue?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, ssis

Hi all i'm banging my head against a wall with this one and hope someone can help. I have a ssis package written in BIDS 2005, which basically selects some data rows from a table in DatabaseA and transfers the data to a table in DatabaseB. Its a fairly straightforward and easy SSIS package. I've installed the package on our dev server (which is running sql server 2008 r2) into integration services. When i'm logged onto the server with my username (v_ashby-smith) and run the package directly through integration services, the package completes successfully and moves the data across as expected.

I want the package to run on a schedule so i've created a job under sql server agent. Now when i run the job the package says it completes successfully, however when inspecting the destination database table (DatabaseB), all the data in the table has been wiped!! The SSIS package does not do any sort of delete it literally just copies data across. The sql server agent services has been set to run as a domain user COMPANY\devsqladm and a user in sql server has been created with the necessary permissions to access the required databases.

To also add to the puzzle, when i run the package in BIDS, it works fine and copies the data across as expected!

If anyone has any ideas i would really appreciate it, this should be alot simpler than it is turning out to be!!

Comment: So there is only one item in the "steps" list of you SQL Server Agent job, and all that does is run the SSIS package, correct?

Comment: When using the Import/Export wizard in SQL Server Management Studio, there is a setting to [delete rows from destination table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189660.aspx).  I know you're not using that wizard, but I wonder if that's getting turned on somehow when you transfer the package from BIDS to the SSIS Package store.  I *really* don't think that would happen, but just something to check for.

Comment: How is this question different from your other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7527218/ssis-package-runs-fine-in-bids-but-wipes-out-tables-when-used-in-sql-server-agent

Comment: @billinkc That question is *mysteriously* gone now (voluntarily removed by author).

Answer (score 0):

SSIS Package nor SQL Agent deletes anything by default... the deletion is either happening inside the package (which is usually the first task if you selected "delete rows" option) or there's a delete logic as a separate step in the agent.

You might want to run the profiler to see what exactly is being called. Or maybe try remove delete permissions from the user to see if the package fails.

Unfortunately, the information given is not enough.

Comment: Maybe package is set up to ignore errors? and that's why it completes without throwing an error?